# Getting number in decimal javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have tried parseFloat, parseInt but it is not working as well

take an example

```
var a = $ 1,2000
var b = a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""); //I use this to strip the currency off
```

so how can I get the 1,20 ?
and for another example if

```
var a = $ 7,0000
```

how can I return a as 7?

I use the parseFloat() but it returns unwanted data.

for example

```
if var a = $ 2,500
```

it returns me

```
var a = 2500
```

that is not what I want. can anybody help me?

Comment: I think you meant `var a = "$ 1,2000";` or alike? Your question doesn't make any sense without your variables being strings

Comment: Commas are used to divide 3 digits per time (thousands, millions), while dots are used to get decimals. Once you sort this out use the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to limit the digits after the dot.

Comment: `$ 1,2000` and `if var` are SyntaxError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your strings are using commas instead of the default decimal separator `.` you will have to replace also the comma

```
var a = "$ 1,2000";
var b = a.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "").replace(",", ".");
var bf = parseFloat(b);  // will give you 1.2
```

Comment: [At least half of all countries use a decimal comma instead of the decimal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system).

Comment: I do so, too. But my Javascript interpreters just don't :-)

Comment: True, JS definitely doesn't use decimal commas. It just so turns out that JS was created in a country who doesn't use decimal commas.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable contains **$ symbol**, then `typeof` your variable is ***string*** and not ***number***. Remember put it inside **quotation marks**, another way, you'll get an error.

```
var a = $ 1,200     //Incorrect syntax
var b = "$ 1,200"     //Correct syntax
```